# Magento 1.7 With PayPal Error when placing order "OrderReviewController is not defined"

Tags: javascript, magento, paypal

I am getting this error:

```
"OrderReviewController is not defined"
```

Trying to checkout with paypal through Magento 1.7.0.

This is the error I get in console, if you need more detail, ask.

This is on the Magento page: https://domain.com/magento-isntall/paypal/express/review/

Thanks for anything,

Comment: Is this a default magento setup? Have you added anything at all into the installation (exclude code added into app/design, skin/)

Comment: Completely default settings with 1 store 1 site using modern skin. I have "extended options" installed.

Comment: What's 'extended options'? Is it a module? Do you have a link to its Magento Connect page?

Comment: I believe it is a custom plugin, no connect page, but I know it is not causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

- Check if some Magento Extension adding JS through front-end layout
  xml.
- Then Overwrite them by putting them in your theme folder (your_theme/layout).
- Put those JS inside pages in which they are actually required.
- If those JS are coming on checkout page then encapsulate them into there scope.

  Like for jQuery it could be:

  ```
                   jQuery(function($){
                    //jQuery Code
                   });
  ```

  It will make a scope for prototype (Magento JS framework) and jQuery.